# sweetalert Laravel Greek languege not return correcly

Tags: php, laravel, sweetalert

My Controller

```
 alert()->success(trans('msg.TRANSLATE'), 'success');
 return \Redirect::to('foo');
```

On my blade

```
// This Not Working   
 @if( session()->has('sweet_alert_message'))
        <script>
            swal(
                    {
                        title: "{{ session('sweet_alert_message.title' )}}",
                        text: "{{ session('sweet_alert_message.message')}}",
                        type: "{{ session('sweet_alert_message.type')}}",
                        timer: 3000,
                        showConfirmButton: false
                    }
            );
        </script>
    @endif
```

The problem is Greek language return chinese... 
but if i put greek language directly on swal Greek language working perfect

```
// This example working 
    @if( session()->has('sweet_alert_message'))
        <script>
            swal(
                    {
                        title: "Αυτή η ενέργεια δεν επιτρέπεται",
                        text: "Αυτή η ενέργεια δεν επιτρέπεται",
                        type: "error",
                        timer: 3000,
                        showConfirmButton: false
                    }
            );
        </script>
    @endif
```

Comment: https://github.com/uxweb/sweet-alert/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Solution

```
   $msg =  json_encode(trans('msg.TRANSLATE'));

    alert()->success($msg, 'success');
    return \Redirect::to('foo');
```

Second solution

```
  title: "δεν επιτρέπεται", // Don't use so many latters try somthink like this
```

On me works..